# objectWillChange.send() how exactly does this work?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
func choose(_ card: MemoryGame<String>.Card)
    {
        objectWillChange.send()
        model.choose(card)
    }
```

I have some function here which is in the ViewModel for something I'm making and I just wanna know how exactly does objectWillChange work? Like when it says object what exactly is it referring to? Since I put this in the ViewModel is it saying the ViewModel will change? But then again I put it specifically into this choose function so what relevance does that have? I basically want it to publish that something changed in the model(A card got chosen) which it seems to be doing but I don't fully understand what I stated previously.

Comment: = `self.objectWillChange.send()`, where `self` is `ViewModel`, where `ViewModel` is-a `ObservableObject`, and `objectWillChange` is part of latter... but it is always better if you provide all affected code in question.

Comment: Okay but it doesn't really seem like the viewmodel is changing to me(I don't have the full code at the moment sadly) but also I guess it is since there is a model inside the viewmodel and that model is changing so I guess that implies the viewmodel is also changing. But another question, does it matter where I put this objectWillChange.send() ? And how does the location of where I put that matter?

Comment: Location does not matter, it is just a publisher - it sends event.

Comment: We don't use view models in SwiftUI, you have to learn the View struct and state/binding property wrappers for your view data.

Answer (score 9):

`objectWillChange` is a property defined on the `ObservableObject` protocol as you can see in the [documentation of ObservableObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject).

The compiler synthesises a default implementation for the property, which emits a value whenever any `@Published` properties of the object changes.

SwiftUI uses the `objectWillChange` `Publisher` to update the `View` when you store an object as `@ObservedObject` (or `@StateObject` or `@EnvironmentObject`) on the view.

You can also manually send updates through `objectWillChange` using its `send()` method when you need to manually update the view.

See a simplified example below:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var published: Int = 0
    var nonPublished: Int = 0
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    ...
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
let view = MyView(viewModel: viewModel)
viewModel.published = 1 // viewModel.objectWillChange emits a value here and view will be updated
viewModel.nonPublished = 2 // viewModel.objectWillChange does not emit a value here and view will not be updated
```